# Active Directory Logs

Tags: active-directory

My laptop is currently connected to an Active Directory and has restrictions in installing application. If I install applications using the admin account does it prompt the Domain Controller that someone is using the admin account?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is more a server-administration question, which is better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: But the short answer is: There will be an event in the Event Viewer on the domain controller saying that "this user authenticated from this computer", but those logs are really, really busy. There is so much data there. No one would notice unless they've setup monitoring for that specific event.

Comment: Thank you, but does it still log on the event viewer on the domain controller if I am not connected to the network?

Comment: Well no, there is no way for it to. It will be logged in the Security log of your laptop. But again, that's a super busy log.